# How to integrate Microsoft Intunes with Ionic application?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, mdm

I have an ionic application and i want to integrate microsoft intunes with my android as well as ios app. When i searched online, i came across this **[Microsoft Intune App SDK Cordova Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ms-intune-mam)**.

But it says 'This package has been deprecated'. Is there any other way to integrate Ionic app with Microsoft Intunes?

Comment: did you found any solution for it ?

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: no, nothing yet